# Will Apple reject my App if I change the color of the MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, email, customization

Can anybody please answer the following question: Has any app ever been rejected by apple for changing the color of the MFMailComposeViewController?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note make sure you test your implementation works on iOS6 as MFMailComposeViewController has a bad habit of crashing under certain circumstances on iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the color using the appearance property (**UIAppearance**) then apple won't reject your App.

Note:
I have an app in Appstore which had a MFMessageComposeViewController with custom color.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any private api ? If yes then apple will reject your app because apple doesn't allow to use private api's.

For better solution read apple guidelines.

Hope it helps you.